Is there a household item that can serve as a membrane for osmosis?
I would like to do this kind of an osmosis experiment. I plan to use NaCl as the solute, but it is unclear to me what to use for the membrane. With a quick search, I only find industrial or laboratory equipment (such as this), which is overkill for my purposes (I would just like to see osmotic pressure with my own eyes and maybe check the van 't Hoof law). Is there some reasonably accessible material that lets water through, but not salt?

Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

@rob Is it okay if I crosspost it there? (the policy at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu doesn't seem to have reached a consensus)

It's usually okay. It's polite to edit each question so that it contains a link to its twin on the other site.

A known membrane for osmosis is cellophane foil. Historically, it was the first osmosis membrane used for dialysis. It is also a foil frequently used in household.

Natural living cell membranes.
Not quite the same experiment, but still: drop a fresh potato into very salty water. After a while, the potato should visibly shrink.
You can also use your own body: immerse yourself in fresh water and your skin will absorb the water, increasing its volume.
Cut off the top of any growing plant. Soon you will see water pumped out of the soil where the cut was made.
All these effect are caused by osmosis.

This is in principle true, and thanks, but what I would really like is to see the nonintuitive image of water columns of different height being balanced. And since osmosis is often drawn that way, I hoped the experiment would actually be realisable that way.

You might try to take the membrane that lies inside the hard shell of an egg. I've never done it, so it might be almost impossible to do!

The first kidney dialysis machine, developed in Holland during WWII, used beverage cans, a washing machine and sausage casing.  Sort of household items...
